# Defining a custom predicate as a combination of std::is_same

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I have a function template and I'd like to restrict the set of types for which it can be instantiated.

I wrote something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething( /* ... Some parameters involving T ... */) 
{
  // Check at compile-time that T is allowed
  static_assert(
      std::is_same<T, int>::value 
      || std::is_same<T, float>::value
      || std::is_same<T, double>::value
      ...
      || std::is_same<T, /* other type */>::value,
      "Type not allowed");
}
```

I have to repeat the same check for other function templates.

An obvious solution would be copy-and-paste'ing the above `static_assert` check, but that would be bad for code maintainability.

A better solution might be to wrap the `static_assert` check in an *ad hoc* helper function, and call it in each function templates in which I need the type check.

But what I think would be more elegant is defining a **custom combination** of `std::is_same` calls, that I could use like this:

```
static_assert(IsTypeAllowed<T>::value, "Type not allowed");
```

How can I define my custom `IsTypeAllowed<T>` as a combination of `std::is_same` calls `||`'ed together?

Comment: If you just want to exclude integral types, you can use [`std::is_integral<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thanks, I knew `std::is_integral`, but it's a specific subset selection (there are also other custom types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++1z you can roll your own trait with [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction):

```
template<typename T, typename... Others>
struct is_any : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Others>...>
{
};
```

Then it's as simple as

```
static_assert(!is_any<int,char,bool>::value);
//static_assert(!is_any<int,char,bool,int>::value); //error
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/d81sxmojcLj3rwpJ)

You can map it further to get the exact interface you asked for:

```
template<typename T>
using IsTypeAllowed = std::bool_constant<!is_any<T, char, bool, int>::value>;
```

---

If you need this in C++14, you needn't look father than the possible implementation provided by cppreference:

```
template<class...> struct disjunction : std::false_type { };
template<class B1> struct disjunction<B1> : B1 { };
template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct disjunction<B1, Bn...> 
    : std::conditional_t<B1::value != false, B1, disjunction<Bn...>>  { };
```